# How to access main html page to another html page?

Tags: html

I have the main HTML page and another HTML page are located in the C:\Users\computer\Pictures. When I run the main HTML page and click on the link to another HTML page, it says "file not found. It may have been moved or deleted. ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND."

I haven't moved and deleted the files since I saved HTML files in the C:\Users\computer\Pictures.

Here is the HTML code

```
<div id="Border" class="">

    <div id="Topic_List" class="creature">
        <ul id="ListName" class="">
            <li><a href="C:\\Users\\computer\\Pictures\\home.html"> home </a></li>
            <li><a href="C:\\Users\\computer\\Pictures\\life.html">Life</a></li>
            <li><a href="C:\\Users\\computer\\Pictures\\interest.html"> Interest </a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>


</div>
```

Here is another HTML page

```
<style>
 #Content{margin:5px auto;padding:0;width:600px;height:auto;border:1px solid #666;background-color:#f1f1f1}
 #col{margin:5px;padding:0;width:590px;height:auto;}
</style>
<body>

<div id="Content" class="">
<div id="col" class="">
<p><font size="5" >
    Hello, Welcome to my home page
</font>
</p>
<h1  align="center"> Activities </h1>
<p><font size="5" > 

    <ul id="ActivitiesList" class="">
    <li> Soccer </li>
    <li>Football</li>
    </ul>

</font></p>


<p>


</div>
</div>
```

Comment: where is the current code located?

Comment: Try `href="home.html"`

Comment: Depperm, they are in the C:\Users\computer\Pictures.

Comment: DontVoteMeDown, I tried that way too but the result was the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: I use URIs like this all the time.

```
    <div id="Topic_List" class="creature">
        <ul id="ListName" class="">
            <li><a href="file:///C:/Users/computer/Pictures/home.html"> home </a></li>
            <li><a href="file:///C:/Users/computer/Pictures/life.html">Life</a></li>
            <li><a href="file:///C:/Users/computer/Pictures/interest.html"> Interest </a></li>


        </ul>

    </div>


</div>
```

If your index.html is in the same folder this should work:

```
<div id="Border" class="">

    <div id="Topic_List" class="creature">
        <ul id="ListName" class="">
            <li><a href="home.html"> home </a></li>
            <li><a href="life.html">Life</a></li>
            <li><a href="interest.html"> Interest </a></li>


        </ul>

    </div>


</div>
```

If you get "File not found." As I see you got from the other post, go to the file, shift right click and select "Copy Path" Paste that into a notepad to verify the path is correct.

Comment: It is working now, I didn't change anything from my code. This is crazy

Answer (score 0):

You have a formatting error in `C:\\Users\\computer\\Pictures\\home.html`. You should use `C:/Users/computer/Pictures/home.html`. HTML counts `C:\\...` as 2 slashes, not one. Also, HTML uses forward slashes (`/`) instead of backslashes (`\`).

Comment: VFDan, just now I tried that way but the result is the same "file not found"

Comment: @TulMagar Are you sure the file name is `home.html`? It might be `home.htm`.

Comment: Can you copy my code and check it out in your computer?

Comment: This is crazy, it is working now. I didn't change anything from my code.

Comment: @TulMagar Wow, I don't know! Delete the question then? (also I gave you an upvote)

Comment: I can't delete the question because stack overflow doesn't allow to delete the question. If you try to delete the question many times than you might get block from stack overflow